# Emacs で reStructuredText を編集中する際に、コードブロックを別途シンタックスハイライトしたい

Tags: emacs, sphinx

[Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) を用いて文章作成をしています。
Emacs で以下のような reStructuredText フォーマットのファイルを編集している際に、
コードブロック (code-block) の中身だけ rst-mode とは別のメジャーモードでシンタックスハイライトしたいのですが、どうすれば上手くできるでしょうか。

```
こんにちは世界
==============

- ほげほげ

  .. code-block:: python

     # このブロックは rst-mode ではなく python-mode で
     # シンタックスハイライト + インデントしたいという話です

     def hello():
         print("Hello, world!")

     hello()
```

Answer (score 2):

自分で試せていないのでうまくいくか分からないのですが、mumamoやmmm-modeを使うとひとつのバッファの中で、複数のモードをコードの種類によって切り替えて使うことができます（他にも[EmacsWikiのMultipleModes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes)を参考にしてみてください）。

mmm-modeであれば、やっていることは逆（Pythonコード中のrstを編集する）なのですが、[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493342/have-emacs-edit-python-docstrings-using-rst-mode)や[このコード](https://github.com/mangalam-research/software-standards/blob/master/emacs/mmm-rst-python.el)が設定の参考になるかもしれません。